# Numpy array with symmetric indices

Tags: arrays, numpy

How do I create a numpy array with a symmtric range of indices?
I tried:

```
np.zeros(-100:100,-100:100)
```

expecting an array with index `-100 to +100`.

Answer (score 0):

NumPy doesn't have support for this; indexing always starts at zero. You could try writing your own subclass of `ndarray`, but you'd have a lot of awkward design decisions to make; for example, if you have an array with indices from -100 to 100, where do the indices of `array[1:]` start and end? And how do you broadcast operations across arrays with compatible shapes, but different indices? What would the bounds be of the result of something like `dot`?

Answer (score 0):

After some searching I found this. I really didn't need a symmetrical array index. What I wanted was a way to simply specify a circular aperture without an x,y loop. I really don't understand what this ogrid thingy does, but it works.

Cheers,
Gert

```
import numpy             as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

r= 800
s= 1000

y,x = np.ogrid[-s:s+1, -s:s+1]
mask = x*x + y*y <= r*r
aperture = np.ones((2*s+1, 2*s+1))
aperture[mask] = 0

plt.imshow(aperture)
plt.show()
```